# here api : stop sign near gps coordinate?

Tags: here-api

My car is at 47.9939936, 0.1933996, heading north near a STOP SIGN.

- which is the better Here REST API to answer the question '*is this lat/lon near a stop sign*’ ?

sincerly,

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight API to provide you this information. You have to get the Traffic Signals information in a particular area and have the logic in your code to check if your vehicle is near to the signal. You can get Traffic Sign Information using PDE API.

Update: https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=18135&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1 refer here for the description on interpreting LINK ID and then you can use LINK_FC1 layer to get the lat, lon https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/layer?region=WEU&release=18135&url_root=pde.api.here.com&layer=LINK_FC1

Comment: using the PDE API like this :
[https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?layer=TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC5&app_id=...&app_code=...&level=13&tilex=8198&tiley=6277]
give me a STOP SIGN
but no lat/lon to check if my vehicule is near
Can i retrieve the STOP SIGN lat/lon from LINK_IDS or CONDITION_ID ?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Links are currently broken. Can any one help ?